# How do I build an msi file with cxfreeze

Tags: windows-installer, cx-freeze

I have successfully created an exe with cxfreeze. When I use the option to create a msi file I get the following message at the end of the process:

removing 'build\bdist.win32\msi (and everything under it)

Indeed the bdist.win32 folder is empty. while the exe.win32-2.7 has all of the necessary files including the exe.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look in the dist\ folder.